# Android Studio - How to measure number of references?

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way to understand how many references does a project include? I am trying to stay under the 64k limit but don't know how to count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Classy shark 
https://github.com/google/android-classyshark
Android executable browser which helps you analyse your apk with number of method calls native calls.

Comment: Thanks but how can I use that? Can you help me please?

Comment: download this jar , and open your apk with this , github documentation contains the whole procedure.

Comment: Done! Thank you :)